# How to get the returned value from the delegate call on the function of another contract?

Tags: solidity, delegatecall, callcode

Here is my example:

```
contract A {
    function a() public returns(uint256) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

```
contract B {
    address addrOfA;
    function b() public returns(uint256) {
        (, bytes memory returnData) = addrOfA.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSingature("a()");
        return uint256(returnData);
    }
}
```

What should I do to make the `b()` return 1? How to deal with the return value `returnData` so that I can get the value `1` from the delegate call on `a()`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract A {
    function a() public returns(uint256) {
        return 2;
    }
}

contract B {
    address addrOfA;
    constructor (address _addrOfA) public {
        addrOfA = _addrOfA;
    }
    
    function b() public returns(uint256) {
        (bool success, bytes memory result) = address(addrOfA).delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("a()"));
        require(success);
        
        return abi.decode(result, (uint256));
    }
}
```

I set the `contract A` address in `contract B` constructor just for the sake of the test, you can change that.